# WPF ListView Items Add executing but not showing

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, gridview

I am trying to populate my List View which is basically a comparison between 2 folders.
I am using WPF List View :

XAML :

```
        <ListView x:Name="listView" Margin="0,39,0,0">
           <ListView.View>
                   <GridView x:Name="gridView"/>               
           </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

MainWindow :

```
private void compare_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {   
            .
            .
            .
            ListHelper listHelper = new ListHelper(listView, gridView);
            CompareResults = results.CoalescedResults();
            listHelper.AddItems(CompareResults);
        }
```

ListHelper Class

```
class ListHelper
    {
        public ListView listView { get; set; }
        public GridView gridView { get; set; }

        public ListHelper (ListView list, GridView grid)
        {
            this.listView = list;
            this.gridView = grid;
            listView.View = gridView;
            InitializeList();
        }

        public void InitializeList()
        {
            listView.Items.Clear();
            // Add columns
            addColumns("File/Folder Name");
            addColumns("Left Folder");
            addColumns("Right Folder");
            addColumns("Match");
        }

       public void addColumns(string colName)
        {
            gridView.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn
            {
                Header = colName,
                DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding(colName),
                Width = 30
            });
        }

        public void AddItems(List<CompareResult> compareResults)
        {
            foreach (var item in compareResults)
            {
                ListDataRow row = new ListDataRow()
                {
                    TypeName = item.GetFileOrFolderName(),
                    LeftFolder = item.LeftFilePath != string.Empty ? Path.GetDirectoryName(item.LeftFilePath) : string.Empty,
                    RightFolder = item.RightFilePath != string.Empty ? Path.GetDirectoryName(item.RightFilePath) : string.Empty,
                    MatchStatus = "MATCH STATUS TEMP"
                };
                listView.Items.Add(row);
            }
        }
```

ListDataRow

```
public class ListDataRow
    {
        public string TypeName { get; set; }
        public string LeftFolder { get; set; }
        public string RightFolder { get; set; }
        public string MatchStatus { get; set; }
    }
```

Now on adding breakpoints, I can see that valid data in being inserted in listView Add items call..
But on execution, only columns are visible, no data items.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone,

I figured out the error.
Please match the Names of Columns with the object (ListDataRow in above example)